# A python function that finds a number's largest divisor excluding itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I write this code:

```
n = int(input('num: '))

for i in range(2, n):
    if n%i == 0:
        a = i
print(a)
```

It works without a problem.

But this creates a problem. It says

> local variable `a` referenced before assignment

```
def largestDivisor(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            a = i
    return a
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your title should reflect your issue, not what you're doing ;)

Comment: How about you find the smallest and do a division?

Answer (score 2):

If you call like `largestDivisor(2)` you won't go in the `for` so not in the `if` and you'll never define `a`, define it at the beginning :

```
def largestDivisor(n):
    a = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            a = i
    return a
```

Comment: Correct. Duplicate of my answer.

Comment: @JimG. we just answered at the same time :D

Answer (score 0):

If the condition "n % i == 0" is never True the variable "a" will not exist, therefore you must initialize it before the loop.

```
def largestDivisor(n):
    a = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            a = i
    return a
```

Comment: Correct. Duplicate of my answer.

Comment: I guess we answered at the same time @JimG.

Answer (score 0):

```
def largestDivisor(n):
    a = 1
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            a=i
    return a
```